# PHP disable cURL verifypeer

Tags: php, ssl

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_exec($ch);

    $response = file_get_contents(base_url()."assets/developed/images/center-poster-bg-transparent.png", false, stream_context_create($context));
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($response);

    $image_to_copy = imagecreatefrompng(base_url()."assets/developed/profile_images/2948721.png");

    imagecopy($im, $image_to_copy, 0, 0, 0, 0, 542, 671);

    imagepng($im, APPPATH."../TESTIMAGE.png");

    curl_close($ch);
```

Can anybody tell me why the above code would give me the error:

`Message: imagecreatefrompng(): SSL operation failed with code 1`

`Message: imagecreatefrompng(): Failed to enable crypto`

I am trying to disable SSL so it will submit but it is not working.

Comment: Why are you using `curl`? You haven't defined `$context` anywhere.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do but it is wrong. The settings passed into CURL do not affect how `imagecreatefrompng()` works. You need to feed the result of `curl_exec($ch);` into `imagecreatefrompng()`.